# Test from job interview

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just came back from job interview. I had this question:

I have table with 3 columns `Student, Profession, Mark`

Each student studies more than 1 profession.

I need to write SQL Server query that return the distinct name of the students that have mark 100 both Mathematics and Physics(AND)

Any idea how to implement this question?

This is my attempt: (it's not perfect...)

```
SELECT *  FROM Marks
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT Student_Name  WHERE (Profession='Physics')AND(Mark=100)
   UNION 
   SELECT Student_Name WHERE (Profession='Mathematics')AND(Mark=100)
  )
  AS Question
```

Comment: Since that's an interview question, I have a return question for you: Are you sure you cannot answer it yourself?

Comment: @WilliamM-B His query doesn't give the right answer. Maybe not...

Answer (score 10):

This can be done with a `JOIN`, but I prefer to do a single scan where possible.

```
SELECT
   M.Student_Name
FROM
   dbo.Marks M
WHERE
   M.Profession IN ('Physics', 'Mathematics')
   AND M.Mark = 100
GROUP BY
   M.Student_Name
HAVING
   Count(DISTINCT M.Profession) = 2
;
```

If, on the other hand, the table has indexes on the `Profession` and/or `Mark` columns, it *may* be better to do a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   P.Student_Name
FROM
   dbo.Marks P
   INNER JOIN dbo.Marks M
      ON P.Student_Name = M.Student_Name
WHERE
   P.Profession = 'Physics'
   AND P.Mark = 100
   AND M.Profession = 'Mathematics'
   AND M.Mark = 100
;
```

Comment: And there's the answer to the softball interview question which easily gets you to the top of the list =)

Comment: What's the softball interview question?

Comment: The question that is being answered here. I'd maybe also add that this is not a properly normalized database design and maybe get a discussion on that going (OLTP vs. OLAP for example)

Comment: By that I just meant interview questions like this are usually geared toward testing *basic* understanding.

Comment: @confusopoly You're absolutely right--I thought about that myself. But the interview of a knowledgeable expert would quickly steer toward more expert topics...

Comment: I'm having no luck finding info on the syntax: FROM dbo.Marks M.  Anyone?

Comment: @7stud `dbo` is the schema. `M` is an alias

Comment: @7stud technically it should be `FROM dbo.Marks AS M` but I prefer not using `AS` because it's not required in SQL Server and I think it clutters things up.

Comment: @ErikE, But so much clearer with AS. It was obviously an alias, I just couldn't find any documentation for an alias without AS.  Thanks.

Comment: @7stud Clarity is about what you are used to; about what you program your mind to understand. If you were to adopt the way I do it, soon you would see `AS` as extra and unneeded clutter. I prefer a higher signal-to-noise ratio and I generally like to drop unnecessary words.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Student from Marks where Profession = 'Mathematics' and marks = 100
intersect
Select Student from Marks where Profession = 'Physics' and marks = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.student_name
from tab t
join tab p on t.student_name = p.student_name and 
    p.Profession='Physics' AND p.Mark=100
where t.Profession='Mathematics' AND t.Mark=100
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple inner join would do it.

```
SELECT physics.Student FROM 
Marks physics
JOIN Marks math ON physics.Student = math.Student
WHERE physics.Profession='Physics'
AND math.Profession='Math'
AND physics.Mark = 100
AND math.Mark = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student_Name
FROM Marks
WHERE (Profession = 'Physics' AND Mark = 100)
   AND Student_Name IN (SELECT Student_Name
                        FROM Marks
                        WHERE Profession = 'Mathematics' AND Mark = 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.student
from
   (select student, 
   count(distinct profession) as profession_count,
   avg(mark) as avg_mark
   from marks
   where profession in ('mathmatics', physics')
   group by student) a
where a.profession_count >= 2
and a.avg_mark = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT name FROM a WHERE prof = 'phy' AND mar = '100' AND name IN (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM a WHERE prof = 'math' AND mar = '100' )